# Almost free actions on simply-connected spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a simply-connected compact topological group (you can think of $SU(n)$ if you like it more concrete), and let $X$ be a finite-dimensional simply-connected $G$-CW-complex. If we know that all the isotropy groups are finite, does this imply they are trivial? And if not, are they at least bounded in size (in some sense)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it was requested, here is the answer (from the comment) again.

The statement is wrong. For each $k$, one can start with a unique $0$-cell $G/(\mathbb Z/k)$ and attach a $2$-cell $G \times D^2$ by a map $G \times S^1 \to G/(\mathbb Z/k)$ that equivariantly extends a generator $S^1 \to G/(\mathbb Z/k)$ of the fundamental group $\pi_1(G/(\mathbb Z/k)) = \mathbb Z/k$. The resulting $G$-CW complex will be simply-connected, with finite, but non-trivial isotropy subgroups.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: This is wrong,  as Jens explains below.

It is enough to show that the isotropy groups of the 0-cells are trivial: higher dimensional cells must have smaller isotropy.

We may suppose, by restricting to $G$-skeleta, that $X$ only has $G$-CW-cells of dimension $\leq 1$. Then $X$ is path-connected if and only if $X/G$ is, in which case its fundamental group is given by the fundamental group of the graph of groups with underlying graph $X/G$ and edges and vertices decorated by their (finite) isotropy groups. The fundamental group of $X$ is therefore obtained as an amalgamated free product followed by HNN extensions (where all homomorphisms are given by conjugation in $G$, so in particular are injective). An HNN extension is never trivial (as it has $\mathbb{Z}$ as a quotient) and an amalgamated free product of non-trivial groups (along injective homomorphisms) is never trivial. Thus if $X$ is simply-connected then the isotropy of the 0-cells must be trivial, as required.

Comment: I am skeptical about this argument. Why can we assume that there are only G-cells of dimension $\leq 1$? Actually, why can't we start with $G/(\mathbb Z/k)$ for $k$ arbitrarily large (that is the unique 0-cell) and attach a 2-cell $G \times D^2$ via a map that equivariantly extends a generator $S^1 \to G/(\mathbb Z/k)$ of the fundamental group $\pi_1(G/(\mathbb Z/k)) = \mathbb Z/k$? This example should answer my question in the negative.

Comment: I suppose that is right. I had mistakenly thought that because G is simply-connected that 2-cells and higher did not matter for the fundamental group , but of course the trivial group shows this is not the case...

Comment: @JensReinhold, since your comment seems to answer the question, why don't you post it as an answer?